# extract a line that matches a string with IP address

Tags: python, regex, ip-address, python-2.x

I am working on python to find a line that matches a particular pattern of an IP address.

```
f = open('file.txt','r')
for line in f:
    if line.find("N2:42.61.0.69")
        print line
```

The pattern that I am trying to match is `"node number":"IP address"`, where 
`"node number"` is the alphabet 'N' followed by a 'number'. Such as N23, N456, N98765, etc.

I used the pattern `N2:42\.61\.0\.69`, but it didn't yield any result.

Most of the examples talks about regex to match a particular pattern such as for an IP address `"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$"`.

But here I want to **match a particular string with IP address**. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your question title is rather at odds with the penultimate line in your question. You just want to match a string, nothing to do with an IP address.

Comment: `N2:42/.61/.0/.69`: use backslashes instead if you want to escape the `.`.

Comment: I want to match a string that contains an IP address. I also escaped it with /. I have mentioned it before.

Comment: For clarification please give a sample input and the desired output for that sample.

Comment: '/' is not an escape character in Python.

Comment: A sample line in input file would be
"link L518523:  N2:42.61.0.69 N248066".
I am trying to match "N2:42.61.0.69" and extract whole line from the file.

Comment: oops... it was supposed to be '\' backslash. I tried with backslashes it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The function find():

> Returns the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

So if you want to find lines containing the given string( "N2:42.61.0.69" in your case), the condition should be:

```
if line.find("N2:42.61.0.69") != -1:
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
(?:^|\s*)N\d+:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?:$|\s+)
```

[REGEX 101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qO7tB1/3)

In python 2.7, to use the pattern in your example, you could:

```
import re
p = '(?:^|\s*)N\d+:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?:$|\s+)'
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if re.findall(p, line) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the value of the node may change, but the value of the IP address is known and fixed.  Since the dot has a special meaning in regular expressions, you must place a backslash before.

```
import re
REGEX = re.compile( r"^N\d+:42\.61\.0\.69$" )
f = open('file.txt','r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()  
    if REGEX.match(line):
        print line
f.close()
```

Notice the use of a raw string (`r" ..."`), without it all the backslashes would need to appear twice (`\\`).  Also, the `^` at the beginning and the `$` at the end are used to match the whole line. If other text can appear in the lines, you can remove them and use `search` instead of `match`.  The `rstrip()` is used to remove end-of-line characters (`\n` for example).

When used with the following data (contents of `file.txt`)

```
N1:42.61.0.69
N2:10.0.0.1
N123456:42.61.0.69
```

it prints only the first and third lines

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process `file.txt` a line at a time, the following should work:

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        match = re.search(r'(.*?(N\d+):42\.61\.0\.69 .*?)', line)

        if match:
            line, node_number = match.groups()
            print "{} found in {}".format(node_number, line)
```

Given `file.txt` contains the following:

```
link L518523: N1:42.61.0.69 N248066
non matching line
link L518533: N2:42.61.0.69 N248066
link L518553: N3:43.61.0.69 N248066
link L518553: N4:42.61.0.69 N248066
```

You would get the following output:

```
N1 found in link L518523: N1:42.61.0.69 
N2 found in link L518533: N2:42.61.0.69 
N4 found in link L518553: N4:42.61.0.69
```